# Automatic screen rotate on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, rotation, screen, display

Is something solution for coercion screen rotate?
For example i have phone with display 540x960 and implicitly every site will display vertical. I would to automatic change view during first open on horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something I'm missing, but have you tried?

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-orientation-styles/